# Paypal: Cancel or timeout a payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-soap

I'm using Adaptive Payments API in order to create a new parallel payment. I'm reading documentation but I still have some questions:

- Is there any API operation for cancel this payment (obviously, sending payKey)?
- When I create this payment, can I specify a timeout?
- What is the default timeout for a paypal operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [same question asked and answered](https://www.x.com/message/180992) in the PayPal X Developer Network:

> At this time, there is not a way to cancel a paykey and a timeout value cannot be specified.  The default timeout value for PayPal is 5 minutes (after being inactive) however a paykey is good for 3 hours.  So if the user were to copy the redirect url (before logging in), that url (with paykey) would be good for 3 hours.